# Olympiad Inequality $\frac{ab+bc+ca}{a+b+c}(\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{2a+b})\leq 1$ with proof (long post)

Tags: proof-verification, inequality, contest-math, alternative-proof, jensen-inequality

It takes me a lot a time to solve this :

> Let $a,b,c>0$ with $a\geq b\geq c$ then we have :
>   $$\frac{ab+bc+ca}{a+b+c}(\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{2a+b})\leq 1$$

My proof :
We need some lemmas to begin :

> First lemma :
>   Let $x,y>0$ then we have :
>   $$\frac{x}{x+\frac{1}{2}}+\frac{y}{y+\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{\frac{x+y}{2}}{\frac{x+y}{2}+\frac{1}{2}}+\frac{p}{p+\frac{1}{2}}$$
>   Where $p$ is equal to:
>   $$\frac{\frac{x}{(x+\frac{1}{2})^2}+\frac{y}{(y+\frac{1}{2})^2}}{\frac{1}{(x+\frac{1}{2})^2}+\frac{1}{(y+\frac{1}{2})^2}}$$

the proof is easy it's just calculus .

> Second lemma :
>   With the notation of the first lemma we have :
>   $$\frac{\frac{x+y}{2}}{\frac{x+y}{2}+\frac{1}{2}}\geq \frac{p}{p+\frac{1}{2}}$$

Proof :

With the first lemma and the concavity of $\frac{x}{x+\frac{1}{2}}$ and the use of Jensen's inequality :

$$\frac{x}{x+\frac{1}{2}}+\frac{y}{y+\frac{1}{2}}-\frac{\frac{x+y}{2}}{\frac{x+y}{2}+\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{p}{p+\frac{1}{2}}\leq \frac{\frac{x+y}{2}}{\frac{x+y}{2}+\frac{1}{2}} $$

Now we attack the problem :

We prove a stronger result :

We have with $x=\frac{1}{a}$ and $y=\frac{1}{b}$ and $z=\frac{1}{c}$:

$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{2a+b}+\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{2b+a}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{xy}{2x+y}+\sum_{cyc}\frac{xy}{2y+x}$$

But :

$$\frac{xy}{2x+y}+\frac{yz}{2z+y}=y(\frac{\frac{1}{2}\frac{x}{y}}{\frac{x}{y}+\frac{1}{2}}+\frac{\frac{1}{2}\frac{z}{y}}{\frac{z}{y}+\frac{1}{2}})$$

Now we apply the first lemma to get :

$$y(\frac{\frac{1}{2}\frac{x}{y}}{\frac{x}{y}+\frac{1}{2}}+\frac{\frac{1}{2}\frac{z}{y}}{\frac{z}{y}+\frac{1}{2}})=\frac{\frac{x+z}{4}}{\frac{\frac{x}{y}+\frac{x}{y}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}}+Q$$

Finally we have :

$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{xy}{2x+y}+\sum_{cyc}\frac{xy}{2y+x}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{\frac{x+z}{4}}{\frac{\frac{x}{y}+\frac{x}{y}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}}+Q+R+T$$
We multiply by $\frac{x+y+z}{xy+yz+zx}$ :
$$\frac{x+y+z}{xy+yz+zx}(\sum_{cyc}\frac{xy}{2x+y}+\sum_{cyc}\frac{xy}{2y+x})=\frac{x+y+z}{xy+yz+zx}(\sum_{cyc}\frac{\frac{x+z}{4}}{\frac{\frac{x}{y}+\frac{x}{y}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}})+\frac{x+y+z}{xy+yz+zx}(Q+R+T)$$

But :

$$\frac{x+y+z}{xy+yz+zx}(\sum_{cyc}\frac{\frac{x+z}{4}}{\frac{\frac{x}{y}+\frac{x}{y}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}})=1$$

And with the second lemma we have :

$$\frac{x+y+z}{xy+yz+zx}(\sum_{cyc}\frac{\frac{x+z}{4}}{\frac{\frac{x}{y}+\frac{x}{y}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}})=1\geq\frac{x+y+z}{xy+yz+zx}(Q+R+T)$$

So we prove :

$$\frac{x+y+z}{xy+yz+zx}(\sum_{cyc}\frac{xy}{2x+y}+\sum_{cyc}\frac{xy}{2y+x})\leq 2$$

Or 
$$\frac{ab+bc+ca}{a+b+c}(\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{2a+b}+\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{2b+a})\leq 2$$

But :

$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{2a+b}-\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{2b+a}= -\frac{(2 (a - b) (a - c) (b - c) (2 a^2 + 7 a b + 7 a c + 2 b^2 + 7 b c + 2 c^2))}{((2 a + b) (a + 2 b) (2 a + c) (a + 2 c) (2 b + c) (b + 2 c))}$$

And with the condition $a\geq b\geq c$ it's negative so :

$$2\frac{ab+bc+ca}{a+b+c}(\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{2a+b})\leq\frac{ab+bc+ca}{a+b+c}(\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{2a+b}+\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{2b+a})\leq 2$$

Done !

My question is have you an alternative proof ?

Thanks a  lot for your time !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative, while not shorter, it can be brute-forced with just elementary algebra . . .

Since the $\text{LHS}$ is homogeneous, we can assume $c=1$, and $a\ge b \ge 1$.

Replacing $c$ by $1$, and simplifying, we get 
$$
1-\text{LHS}
=
\frac
{-a^2b+2a^3b-a^2-ab^2-a^2b^2-ab+2b^3-b^2+2a}
{(a+b+1)(2a+b)(2b+1)(2+a)}
$$
so it remains to show
$$
-a^2b+2a^3b-a^2-ab^2-a^2b^2-ab+2b^3-b^2+2a\ge 0
$$
Replacing $b$ by $1+x$ and $a$ by $1+x+y$, the $\text{LHS}$ of the above inequality simplifies to
$$
3x^2+3xy+3y^2+9x^2y+9y^2x+4x^3y+5y^2x^2+2y^3x+4x^3+2y^3+x^4
$$
which is nonnegative since all coefficients are positive and $x,y\ge 0$.

Comment: How did you think of the replacements? Is there some way of thinking about getting positive coefficients?

Comment: @Rishabh Jain: Since all variables are positive, homogeneity allows us to force $c=1$, thus eliminating a variable. Since $c=1$, the constraint $b\ge c$ is equivalent to $b=1+x$ where $x\ge 0$, and the constraint $a\ge b$ is then equivalent to $a=1+x+y$ where $y\ge 0$. With those fairly natural substitutions, the new inequality with the constraints $x,y\ge 0$ is equivalent to the old one. The fact that the expansion yields all positive coefficients is just a windfall.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Also, how does homogeneity allow us to put c=1?

Comment: @Rishabh Jain: Let $t$ be an arbitrary positive constant. By homogeneity, the given inequality holds for the triple $(a,b,c)$ if and only if it holds for the triple $(ta,tb,tc)$. Note also that the constraint $a\ge b\ge c > 0$ is equivalent to $ta \ge tb\ge tc > 0$. Then, since $t > 0$ is arbitrary, we can choose $t=1/c$, hence, letting $a'=a/c$ and $b'=b/c$, the given inequality holds for the triple $(a,b,c)$ if and only if it holds for the triple $(a',b',1)$.

Answer (score 0):

After full expanding we need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}(2a^3b-a^2b^2-a^2bc)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^3b+a^3c-a^2b^2-a^2bc)\geq\sum_{cyc}(a^3c-a^3b)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^3b+a^3c-a^2b^2-a^2bc)\geq(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)(a+b+c),$$ which is true because by Muirhead
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^3b+a^3c-a^2b^2-a^2bc)\geq0$$ and by the given $$(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)(a+b+c)\leq0$$